# Update UILabel and TextFields with Updated Data from Parse Database

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I do hope all is well. I am new to Swift. I am building a shell for 2 social app ideas of mine. I have successfully completed login, signup, logout and minimal querying using Parse. Up until now, I have been progressing, however I have reached a mental block.

I created a User Profile ViewController that queries the current user's information from the database and initially displays the results on the in the controller; First Name, Last Name, and etc.

I also created an Edit Profile ViewController that enables the user to update their profile information and logout. So far I have been able to submit the changes to the database, however I am having a hard time having the UILabels and Text Fields update to display the new values.

Some additional insight: Becuase my main view that users are redirected to after successful signin/registration is embedded in a navigation controller which means the navigation bar is inferred.

Please help me!

This is the code for my UserProfileViewController. Please let me knwo if I need to clarify.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

//---------------------------------------
//User Profile View - this can go between viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear functions.
//---------------------------------------

    let userImageFile = PFUser.currentUser()["userProfileImage"] as PFFile

    userImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (imageData: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            var image = UIImage(data:imageData)

            self.currentUserProfilePicture.image = image
        }
    }

    var query = PFUser.query()

    query.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser().objectId)

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock  {
        (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            let user = PFUser.currentUser()

            var firstname = PFUser.currentUser()["firstName"]! as String

            var lastname = PFUser.currentUser()["lastName"]! as String

            var aboutMe = PFUser.currentUser()["aboutMe"]! as String

            self.firstName.text = firstName

            self.lastName.text = lastname

            self.aboutMe.text = aboutMe
            }
    }   
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {

    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi and welcome to swift.

Are you using the prepareForSegue, for sending data between ViewControllers?

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if segue.identifier == "yourIdentifier" //you set the identifier in the storyboard
        {
            var vc = segue.destinationViewController as! YourDestinationViewController //the class of the destination view controller
            vc.someValue = value
            vc.otherValue = otherValue
            vc.dataArray = array //here you set the values in the destination view controller
        }

    }
```

Comment: I am not. It seems as if since it is linked to, from a view that is embedded in a navigation controller, it is sharing some of the unwinding properties. From the edit profile controller, to go back to the profile controller, there is an automatic "back," in the navigation bar. I hope this makes sennse

Comment: Yes, but navigation controller is only for navigation, not for sharing data. Thats prepareForSegue for.

Comment: Thanks for the information! I ended up creating the segue from the Edit Profile controller to the Profile View controller by dragging the connection  form controller to controller. In the Save Changes button, I included the performSegue function that forced the UILabels to refresh with the data from the Parse Database. As an added bonus I was still able to maintain the navigation bar at the top of the screen to enable toggle like function between the views!